# Diferença entre criar uma lista a cada iteração e usar uma list comprehension

Tags: python, for

Eu preciso calcular a distância entre os pontos `(0,0)` e `(1,1)`. Para isso, eu escrevi o seguinte código:

```
def distance(x, y):
   if len(x) != len(y):
       return "x and y não possuem o mesmo comprimento"
   else:
       for i in range(len(x)):
           square_differences = [(x[i] - y[i])**2]
       return math.sqrt(sum(square_differences))

print(distance((0,0),(1,1)))
```

Porém, sempre quando eu rodo obtenho um erro. Entretantoo, se eu mudar a posição do `for` assim:

```
def distance(x, y):
   if len(x) != len(y):
       return "x and y não possuem o mesmo comprimento"
   else:
       square_differences = [(x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(len(x))]
       return math.sqrt(sum(square_differences))

print(distance((0,0),(1,1)))
```

Eu obtenho a resposta correta. Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê?

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi o programa só faz a operação "square_differences" uma vez. Não sei o porquê.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz:

```
square_differences = [(x[i] - y[i])**2]
```

Está criando uma lista contendo um único elemento: o resultado de `(x[i] - y[i])**2`.

E a cada iteração do `for`, você está **sobrescrevendo** o valor de `square_differences`. Ou seja, no final do *loop*, essa variável terá apenas uma lista contendo um único elemento, que é o resultado da conta em questão (para `i` igual a 1). O resultado anterior (para `i` igual a zero) é descartado.

Já quando você faz:

```
square_differences = [(x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(len(x))]
```

Está usando uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), que no fundo é uma forma mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052) de se fazer um *loop*. A linha acima é equivalente a:

```
square_differences = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    square_differences.append((x[i] - y[i])**2)
```

Ou seja, ambas são formas de criar uma lista contendo os resultados das operações. No final, a lista terá 2 elementos (e não apenas um): os resultados do quadrado da diferença entre os respectivos elementos de `x` e `y`.

---

Só para constar, outra forma de fazer seria:

```
def distance(x, y):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise ValueError("x and y não possuem o mesmo comprimento")
    return math.sqrt(sum((ex - ey) ** 2 for ex, ey in zip(x, y)))
```

A soma pode ser feita de uma vez, bastando usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para percorrer ambas as tuplas ao mesmo tempo: a cada iteração, `ex` será um elemento de `x`, e `ey` será um elemento de `y`. O `zip` se encerra quando a menor das listas/tuplas/iteráveis termina, mas como você verifica antes se ambas têm o mesmo tamanho, não haverá problemas em usá-lo aqui.

E em vez da função retornar um número ou uma string, dependendo do caso, fiz ela lançar uma exceção em caso de valores inválidos. Assim, bastaria capturar a exceção para saber se houve erro:

```
try:
    print(distance((0, 1, 2), (1, 1)))
except ValueError as e:
    print('Erro:', e) # Erro: x and y não possuem o mesmo comprimento
```

Repare também que o `else` é desnecessário. Se `x` e `y` tiverem comprimentos diferentes, ele entra no `if` e lança a exceção, interrompendo a execução da função. Se os comprimentos forem iguais, ele não entra no `if` e executa os cálculos, retornando o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando por cima, a sua primeira função armazena um valor único na sua variável square_differences ao final do loop. Já a segunda armazena um array. Para a primeira funcionar você teria que declarar o array fora do loop e usar o método append(). Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi agora.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer apenas calcular a distância entre dois pontos, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import sqrt

p = list(map(int, input('Digite as coordenadas dos pontos: ').split()))
distancia = sqrt(pow((p[2] - p[0]), 2) + pow((p[3] - p[1]), 2))
print('A distancia entre os pontos é: {:.2f}'.format(distancia))
```

Neste algoritmo "p" é uma lista que armazenará o valor das coordenadas dos pontos. Para utilizar corretamente este algoritmo você deve inserir o valor das coordenadas na mesma linha do console, separando-as por um espaço.
Exemplo: Se você quer calcular a distância entre os pontos **(0, 0)** e **(1, 1)**, você deve rodar o programa e digitar as coordenadas "**X1**", espaço, "**Y1**", espaço, "**X2**", espaço e "**Y2**", isto é...

```
Digite as coordenadas dos pontos: 0 0 1 1
```

Em seguida, pressionar "Enter" para obter o resultado. O resultado será impresso da seguinte forma...

```
A distancia entre os pontos é: 1.41
```

Note que a distância está sendo calculada com duas casas decimais.